# Simple Injector using WCF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, simple-injector

I am new to Simple Injector.
I have a WCF service with a class **Testservice** implementing a interface **ITestService**. As per the Simple Injector documentation, in the svc markup I have added the factory attribute as **"SimpleInjector.Integration.Wcf.SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory,       SimpleInjector.Integration.Wcf"**. Also in the AppStart , I have registered the container using the following

```
container.RegisterWcfServices(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); &
container.Register<ITestService, TestService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

The WCF works fine. Now I need to consume the service TestService from my MVC app.
In my MVC App, I have added the **SimpleInjector.Integration.Web** and **SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.MVC** through Nuget and also added the WCF service reference.

I am struck on registering the **TestService** class in App Start of my MVC application in order to inject in my controller. The container needs to be registered as

```
container.Register(ITestService, <TImplementation>);
```

but I am unable to resolve or find out what I need to give on the **TImplementation**. It requires a Implementation class which is the TestService but the TestService is available in WCF componebt and only I have the interface reference  here in my MVC app.

Can somebody guide whether my approach is right and the solution for above. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When you reference a WCF service in another Visual Studio project, Visual Studio generates a proxy implementation of `ITestService` for you. Without using DI, this proxy (typically called `TestServiceClient`) is what you would instantiate. With DI, things are no different: you use that generated `TestServiceClient`.

Comment: When I use the TestServiceClient i get a error    " For the container to be able to create TestServiceClient it should have only one public constructor: it has 5. See https://simpleinjector.org/one-constructor for more information.
Parameter name: implementationType"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a factory method to SimpleInjector in the register method that it will use to build your object.

```
container.Register<ITestService, TestService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Can be written as

```
container.Register<ITestService>(() => new TestServiceClient(), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

You are then free to choose the constructor you want to use in the factory method